# (net was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch, batch-file, script

I am trying to write batch file to map drive when needed but whenever I run it I get an error:

`(net was unexpected at this time`

```
@echo off
SET /P Site=Which site you want to map please type SITE CODE? 
IF %Site% == BPT ( SET /P Drive= C B G?
        IF  %Driv% == C (net use * \\test1\common)
        IF  %Driv% == G (net use * \\test1\global)
        IF %Drive% == B (net use * \\test1\common && net use * \\test1\global))
```

Comment: To add to Mr Harveys awesome suggestions.. Going forward, you remove the `@echo off` and run from the command line (rather than double clicking the batch file).. otherwise, you won't have a hope of figuring out why it is breaking.  Also, NEVER use a variable without quoting both sides.  Otherwise you won't be able to see what breaks if the var doesn't get filled.  `IF "%Driv%"=="C" echo YEP!` NOT `IF %DRIV% == C`

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: the spaces around `==` don't really matter. Actually, the parser *inserts* them if they are not there (and removes superfluous  separators. `if a ; ==  , =  
 a echo hello` does indeed work (parsed as `a == a`)! (Does it make sense? IMHO no, but that's how it works)) The problem here is a simple typo: `drive` gets defined, but `driv` gets compared (not arguing (in fact strongly supporting) the preferred syntax with quotes, as suggested by @SeñorCMasMas).

Comment: @Stephan - It is not that simple. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1621505/109090)

Comment: @dbenham: ah yes, delayed expansion too... "Unnesting" the code (like you did in your answer) eliminates the need of delayed expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from your misspelt DRIV (vs DRIVE), you have a delayed expansion issue.

Your entire IF construct is treated as a single compound statement that is parsed all at once before any code is executed. This is true for any parenthesized block of code.

Percent expansion occurs before the statement is fully parsed, so DRIVE is not yet defined and your 2nd IF statement is read as

```
IF   == C (net use * \\test1\common)
```

You should be able to see how that results in a syntax error.

One solution is to enable delayed expansion and use `!drive!` instead of `%drive%`. That way the entire statement is parsed and then the variable is expanded just before each command is executed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET /P Site=Which site you want to map please type SITE CODE? 
IF %Site% == BPT ( 
  SET /P Drive= C B G?
  IF !Drive! == C net use * \\test1\common
  IF !Drive! == G net use * \\test1\global
  IF !Drive! == B net use * \\test1\common && net use * \\test1\global
)
```

Another option is to use GOTO or CALL to eliminate the large parenthesized block and then you can safely use percent expansion

```
@echo off
SET /P Site=Which site you want to map please type SITE CODE? 
IF %Site% neq BPT goto NotBPT 
SET /P Drive= C B G?
IF %Drive% == C net use * \\test1\common
IF %Drive% == G net use * \\test1\global
IF %Drive% == B net use * \\test1\common && net use * \\test1\global
:NotBPT
```

Another option is to use `CHOICE` instead of `SET /P` and then use `IF ERRORLEVEL` to test the returned error level without needing variable expansion. Note that `if errorlevel 3` is TRUE if error level is greater than or equal to 3. So the IF tests must be done in descending numerical order.

```
@echo off
SET /P Site=Which site you want to map please type SITE CODE? 
IF %Site% == BPT ( 
  choice /c CBG
  if errorlevel 3 (
    net use * \\test1\global
  ) else if errorlevel 2 (
    net use * \\test1\common
    net use * \\test1\global
  ) else if errorlevel 1 (
    net use * \\test1\common
  )
)
```

One advantage of CHOICE over SET /P is you don't have to worry about users entering an incorrect response - CHOICE forces a correct response.

Comment: It would be interesting to add some comments in the cases: **`if /i`** and **`choice /cs`** if  **`%Site% == btp`** result in **`goto NotBPT `**

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe - Yeah, I thought about that. There is also the issue of how to handle or prevent invalid input. But I decided to focus on the central issue.

Comment: Delay expansion one worked for me thanks alot will test other methods as well, i have and other thing to do i have multiple sites so i need to ask if there are more drives to be mapped? so i think we need to go in loop by asking Yes or No so we can enter another site. Can you please provide me a hint how i will be able to do it as i am not a developer just trying to automate my stuff on my own.